# PHP and regexp to accept only Greek characters in form

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that accepts only Greek chars and spaces for a name field in my form (PHP).
I've tried several findings on the net but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Whenever somebody's trying to limit the input range like that, I ask myself: Is it really a good idea? You may well have a valid use case, but often it's overkill - imagine a person with a non-Greek name living in Greece, or a foreigner trying to input a temporary address elsewhere in the world, etc. etc.

Comment: Either way, you should add more information: What character set is the data in that you are comparing? UTF-8?

Comment: Which findings did you try? (Else you might get the exact same suggestions.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not too current on the Greek alphabet, but if you wanted to do this with the Roman alphabet, you would do this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/
```

So to do this with Greek, you replace `a` and `z` with the first and last letters of the Greek alphabet. If I remember right, those are `α` and `ω`. So the code would be:

```
/^[α-ωΑ-Ω\s]*$/
```

Comment: And when greek letters have modifiers with sign above them?

Comment: @blackuprise - That would be a whole different question. It's nontrivial to deal with diacritics.

Comment: @JasonCoyne - That answer doesn't account for capital letters with diacritics, although the `i` flag could solve that. Still, writing them all out doesn't seem like the best approach to me anyway, for a couple of reasons. Either way, if you're the downvoter, see my earlier comment: @blackuprise's question is a different use case. This is the answer to @bikey77's question as written, and apparently it solved the problem.

Answer (score 32):

Full letters solution, with accented letters:

```
/^[A-Za-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+$/
```

Comment: I would suggest the following, in addition to your answer: `/^[A-Za-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+$/`. Notice that I have changed the second range from `A-z` to `a-z`.

Comment: This doesn't catch the other Greek letter accents. See Extended Greek Unicode block.

Comment: This also needs to include Ά, Έ, Ί, Ό, Ύ, Ώ, Ή

Answer (score 12):

The other answers here didn't work for me. Greek Unicode characters are included in the following two blocks

- Greek and Coptic U+0370 to U+03FF (normal Greek letters)
- Greek Extended U+1F00 to U+1FFF (Greek letters with diacritics)

The following regex matches whole Greek words:

```
[\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff]+
```

I will let the reader translate that to whichever programming language format they may be using.

#### See also

- [Unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on leo pal's answer, an even more complete regex, which would accept even capital accented Greek characters, would be the following:

```
/^[α-ωΑ-ΩίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώΊΪΌΆΈΎΫΉΏ\s]+$/
```

With this, you get:

- `α-ω` - lowercase letters
- `Α-Ω` - uppercase letters
- `ίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ` - lowercase letters with all (modern) diacritics
- `ΊΪΌΆΈΎΫΉΏ` - uppercase letters with all (modern) diacritics
- `\s` - any whitespace character

Note: The above does not take into account ancient Greek diacritics (ᾶ, ἀ, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was `/^[a-zA-Z\p{Greek}]+$/u`
source: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php#105324

Answer (score 0):

Greek & Coptic in utf-8 seem to be in the U+0370 - U+03FF range. Be aware: a space, a `-`, a `.` etc. are not....

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed at the excellent site https://regexr.com/ that the range of Greek characters are from "Ά" (902) to "ώ" (974) with 3 characters that are not aphabet characters: "·" (903) and unprintable characters 0907, 0909
So a range `[Ά-ώ]` will cover 99.99% of the cases!

With `(?![·\u0907\u0909])[Ά-ώ]` covers 100%. (I don't check this at PHP though)

Answer (score -1):

The modern Greek alphabet in UTF-8 is in the [U+0386 - U+03CE range](http://la.remifa.so/unicode/unicode.php?start=0386&end=03CE).

So the regex you need to accept Greek only characters is:

```
$regex_gr = '/^[\x{0386}-\x{03CE}]+$/u';
```

or (with spaces)

```
$regex_gr_with_spaces = '/^[\x{0386}-\x{03CE}\s]+$/u';
```

Comment: It looks like this is nearly a copy/paste of the earlier (6+ months earlier) answer... If there's some significant improvement to the earlier answer, it'd be best to outline/explain that. Thanks.