# Regular expression to accept only greek characters

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have this regular expression `^[A-Za-z]{2,3}[0-9]{3,4}$` with which I validate in an input field so that it has 2 or 3 letters and 3 or 4 numbers

I want to accept only greek characters.

I tried this `^[α-ωΑ-Ω]{2,3}[0-9]{3,4}$` from [PHP and regexp to accept only Greek characters in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255329/php-and-regexp-to-accept-only-greek-characters-in-form) but with no luck

i also tried `^[\p{Greek}]{2,3}[0-9]{3,4}$` but again no luck

Any suggestions?

VALID STRINGS: ΚΚΞ542  OOP8888 ΠΠ8965
INVALID STRINGS: 555555 K879 ΓΗΥΟ565

Comment: What does "no luck" mean in practice?

Comment: Did you try it like [`'~^\p{Greek}{2,3}[0-9]{3,4}$~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/odQChv/1)? What are the example valid/invalid strings?

Comment: It means that the field is always invalid even if it has 2 or 3 characters and 3 or 4 letters

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesn' work. i've updated my answer with valid/invalid

Comment: How come `OOP8888` is valid? It has no Greek letters. And [the rest is working well](https://regex101.com/r/odQChv/2).

Comment: ΟΟΡ are greek capital letters

Comment: Wait, they are shown as Latin in your post, and as Greek in the comment text. See https://regex101.com/r/odQChv/3 - it works as expected.

Comment: That second regex works here (tested in JS console).

Comment: Mind that when you copy/paste these chars, they might be re-interpreted as ASCII letters. If your input may contain Latin `O` and `P`, just add to a character class, `[\p{Greek}OP]` and use `i` modifier, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match chars with `\p{Greek}` and you must use the `/u` modifier:

```
'~^\p{Greek}{2,3}[0-9]{3,4}$~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/odQChv/3).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{Greek}{2,3}` - 2 or 3 Greek chars
- `[0-9]{3,4}` - 3 or 4 ASCII digits
- `$` - end of string.

[image]