# Regex condition string contains English AND NOT Greek or vice versa (Greek and not English) only

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a regex in C# code that checks if an input text contains either Greek or English but not both at the same time like the following example:

```
Angela = true
Ανγκελα = true
AngeΛα = false
Αντζela = false
```

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
[a-zA-Z\s]?[α-ωΑ-Ω\s]
[a-zA-Z\s]|[α-ωΑ-Ω\s]
```

[some more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255329/php-and-regexp-to-accept-only-greek-characters-in-form)

Comment: try this `new Regex(@"(^[a-zA-Z\s]*$)|(^[α-ωΑ-Ω\s]*$)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account  the sample input provided in the question, you can use

```js
^(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[α-ωΑ-Ω]+)$
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[α-ωΑ-Ω]+)` - either one or more ASCII letters or one or more Greek letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Perfect thank you! It works as expected. Also thanks for including all additional details.

Comment: @harris Also, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qsejlf/1).